# Android - How to reschedule alarms associated to app events

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-alarms

I found a lot of examples and questions regarding how to fire an alarm using AlarmManager (both periodical or single), but nothing similar to what I need.

My user can schedule a certain number of events (i.e. things to do), with a *single-shot* alarm for each of them to be fired one day before the scheduled start (showing a notification). This is easy.
My problem is that this scheduled start can be changed, thus the alarm should be moved too.

I was thinking to delete the old alarm, and to create a new one considering the new scheduled start. Knowing that I can delete an alarm using `alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent)`, how can I delete the specific alarm related to the rescheduling event? Should I make each alarmIntent unique in some way?
Or there is a better way that I didn't consider (except using Google Calendar APIs to schedule and reschedule an event there, and making it managing the notification)?

Answer (score 0):

While scheduling an alarm using set() API

```
public void set (int type, long triggerAtMillis, PendingIntent operation)
```

in the last argument you can mention a request code using getBroadcast

```
public static PendingIntent getBroadcast (Context context, int requestCode, Intent intent, int flags)
```

an example for this would be :

```
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, id, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

When you want to cancel or reschedule you can use the 'id' to specify which alarm.